# cover of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given a subset $B\subset \mathbb{R^n}$, we've said in our classes that you can 
write down $\mathbb{R^n}=\cup_{j\in  \mathbb{N}}Q_j$ with $\lambda_n(Q_j)=1$ for all $j$. I understand the first part. But why can I write down $\lambda_n(Q_j)=1$? Is it only possible with 1 or is it possible in general with any constant $c$?  ($\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R^n}$)

Comment: What happened to $B$? Did it vanish? And what is $\lambda_n$?

Comment: What are your own thoughts about this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with any positive constant $c$. Just take $A=[0,\sqrt[n]{c}]^n$ and translate it in any direction by (positive) entire multiples of $\sqrt[n]{c}$. (assumming $\lambda_n$· is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: I thought $B$ has to be lebesgue-measurable. So this condition doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

For example for $n=1$ you can consider $Q_i=[-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1+i}{2}]$ that has Lebesgue measure $1$ and these sets cover $\mathbb{R}$

For every $c>0$ you can consider

$Q_i=[-\frac{c}{2}+\frac{i+1}{2},\frac{c}{2}+\frac{1+i}{2}]$

Answer (score 1):

For example let $n=2$ and for $k,m \in \mathbb Z$ let $Q_{k,m}:=[k,k+1] \times [m,m+1].$. The set $M:=\{Q_{k,m}:k,m \in \mathbb Z \}$ is countable, hence $M=\{Q_1,Q_2,...\}, \lambda_2(Q_j)=1$ and $\mathbb{R^2}=\cup_{j\in  \mathbb{N}}Q_j.$